# Perl Dancer/Mojolicious equivlant on golang

Tags: go, perl

I am new to Go programming language and searching of a recommended web framework to use on Go something like Perl Dancer ,any idea?

Comment: Can you detail what features are you looking for in that web framework?

Comment: simple one page web app